# formating hp 16 gp pendrive

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gparted

[image]

[image]

i had formatted my hp 16gb pen drive after installing  os its shows 1.99gb i had tried all no use. i formatted  ntfs, ext4, ext32 different types of formats it shows same thing. in terminal page it not showing sda1 it shows sdb2

Answer (score 0):

**Be careful.**

SDA is your main hard drive **not** your pendrive.

SDA has been partitioned into 2 parts SDA1 which is your OS and and SDA2 which is some spare space at the end left over from the OS installation. It may have been swap space that you have been formatting as `ext4`, `ntfs` etc.

Your pendrive is SDB and this is what you want to format.

You will see this if you unplug your media and, in the terminal

```
lsblk
```

Mine is

```
sda                8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1             8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /home/bu5hman/Work
sdb                8:16   0 978.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1             8:17   0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2             8:18   0 977.9G  0 part
```

Then plug in your media and repeat the command. You will see a new device. In my case `sdc`

```
sda                8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1             8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /home/bu5hman/Work
sdb                8:16   0 978.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1             8:17   0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2             8:18   0 977.9G  0 part 
sdc                8:32   1  57.9G  0 disk 
└─sdc1             8:33   1  57.9G  0 part
```

Partitioning and formatting from the command line is not hard and I would advise you to read any of the online guides, but to get you moving with `GParted`

1. When you have new removable media to partition or format, start
   `GParted` **without** the media plugged.
2. **Still before** you plug the media in. pull down the top right of the `GParted` window, where is says `/dev/sda (149.05Gb)` in your
   screenshot you will see the devices **already connected**. Remember them.
3. **Now** plug in your new media and do step 2 again. You should see a new device listed, this is the new media. select it from the dropdown.
4. With the new device selected (with its name showing in that top right box) you can partition and format it as you like.